# Find multiple of a number that can be written with 1s and 0s

Tags: java, algorithm

Given the number `n` (2 <= n <= 1000), find the lowest nonzero multiple of which is written in base 10 with digits 0 and 1 only. Examples: 2 -> 10, 3 -> 111, 4 -> 100, 7 -> 1001, 11 -> 11, 9 -> 111 111 111.

My idea is not very good: 
 {/* n|2 and n|5  +"000"(max for apparition(2,5)) -> 
      n|3  + "111 "   */}

I think, follow the remaining division of numbers consist of numbers n which is formatted 0/1.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: It looks like you tried to post some code but it's definitely not Java..

Comment: Can you please improve your question, I'm not sure I understand your idea, and I definitely have no idea what the last paragraph should mean.

Comment: is this your question? http://www.spoj.pl/problems/ONEZERO/

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Start by enqueing `1`, since your number must start with a `1`, then each time you extract a number `x` from your queue, see if it's a multiple of `n` or not. If yes, you have your answer, if not insert `x * 10` and `x * 10 + 1` in the queue (in that order).

Note that you do not actually have to store the entire strings of `1`s and `0`s in your queue: it's enough to store the remainder of division by `n` and some auxiliary information that lets you reconstruct the actual string. Write back if you need more details about this.

Answer (score 0):

The non-bruteforce approach would be to iterate throught the series of numbers that contain only 0 and 1 then figure out if the number is a multiple of the number in question. This approach will be substantially more efficient than iterating through the multiples of `n` and determining if it contains only `0` and `1`.

[IVlad's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882190/find-multiple-of-a-number-that-can-be-written-with-1s-and-0s/7882389#7882389) is the more efficient way to produce the series (numbers that contain only `0` and `1`). However, if you prefer to generate the numbers on-the-fly (no memory overheads of the queue) you can simply iterate through the integers (or use your loop index) and for each value interpret its binary representation as a decimal number.

```
2 (Decimal) ->  10 (Binary) -> (interpret as decimal 10)
3 (Decimal) ->  11 (Binary) -> (interpret as decimal 11)
4 (Decimal) -> 100 (Binary) -> (interpret as decimal 100)
5 (Decimal) -> 101 (Binary) -> (interpret as decimal 101)
... and so on.
```

For the conversion, I suspect it can be done by chaining calls to `Integer.toBinaryString()` and `String.parseInt()` but there may well be more efficient ways to do that.

Here's an online demo to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/6j5De/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int result(int num)
{
    int i =2;
    while(true)
    {
        int mult = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(i++,2));
        if( mult % num == 0) //Check whether it is a multipler of given number or not ?
        {
            return mult;
        }
    }
}
```