# Multiple formatted by 0/1

Tags: numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find multiple of a number that can be written with 1s and 0s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882190/find-multiple-of-a-number-that-can-be-written-with-1s-and-0s)

Given the number n (2 <= n <= 1000), find the lowest nonzero multiple of which is written in base 10 with digits 0 and 1 only. Examples: 2 -> 10, 3 -> 111, 4 -> 100, 7 -> 1001, 11 -> 11, 9 -> 111 111 111.

I think, follow the remaining division of numbers consist of numbers n which is formatted 0/1.Thanks for your help!

```
{10/3= 3 remaining 1 -> and the finaly is 111 !!!   
10/4= 4 ramining 2 -> and the finaly is 100 !!!    
10/6= 1 ramainin 4 -> and the finaly is 1110 !!!    
I don't understand is the logic}
```

Comment: I can't seem to figure out what you're asking. (and the first part looks like a homework question).

Comment: This looks like homework

Comment: the question is kind of unclear.

Comment: it really looks like a homework

Comment: This is a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7882190/115845

Answer (score 0):

The question is basically saying: Find the first non-zero multiple of *n* that consists of only 1s and 0s. And we're not talking binary (base 2) or remainders or anything fancy here. Here are some examples, in the format:

```
 n => The first multiple of n with only 1s and 0s is x (n * y = x)
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2 => (2 x 5 = 10)
 3 => (3 x 37 = 111)
 4 => (4 x 25 = 100)
 7 => (7 x 143 = 1001)
11 => (11 x 1 = 11)
 9 => (9 x 12,345,679 = 111,111,111)
```

You need to figure out an algorithm to make it work! You could use brute force:

```
for each n between 2 and 1000
    y = 1
    x = 0
    do
        x = n * y++
    while (x is not 0 and string(x) is not all 0s and 1s)
    print n => x
next n
```

I implemented this in C# to test it and it gave me the following output for *n* between 2 and 10:

```
2 => 10
3 => 111
4 => 100
5 => 10
6 => 1110
7 => 1001
8 => 1000
9 => 111111111
10 => 10
```

There are probably faster implementations, but this should give you an idea of where to start.

Comment: and how to calculate y whatever  n

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for help interpreting the (homework) question, here's what I think it means: "For a given number, find out lowest multiple of it that contains only digits 1 or 0"

So, for example, if the number is 2:

```
Multiples of 2 = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, .... }
                               |
                               |
                       this is your answer!
```

The non-bruteforce way to do this would be to iterate throught numbers that contain only 0 and 1 then figure out if the number is a multiple of the number in question. This approach will be substantially more efficient than iterating through the multiples of `n` and determining if it contains only `0` and `1`.

An easy way to get a list of numbers that contain only `0` and `1` would be iterate throught the integers and for each value, interpret its binary representation as a decimal number.

Here's an online demo to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/6j5De/4/

Since it's likely to be homework, I'll leave it up to you to translate that to your subject language.

Comment: prohibited direct checking multiples of n if composed only of 0 and 1

Comment: @user1011460 updated answer with non brute force method and demo